# C# Decorator Class using Default Class Version of Method

Tags: c#, design-patterns, webdriver, decorator

How do you leave a method the same as the default implementation if trying to decorate a class?

For example I am trying to add a property to a IWebDriver interface of the WebDriver class.

i.e.

```
public class MyWebDriver : IWebDriver
{
    private IWebDriver _driver;
    internal string _currentTest { get; set; }

    internal MyWebDriver(IWebDriver driver)
    {
        _driver = driver;
    }
}
```

Visual Studio IntelliSense had me implement the class (or interface) with a bunch of '`throw new NotImplementedException();` as the method body for the default WebDriver class methods.

i.e.

```
public IWebElement FindElement(By by)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

My question is if I don't want to adjust the behavior of these methods at all how do I implement that? Do I just leave it all as that line in the body or do I have to for example (if this is the case how would it be done for the FindElement method w/ a return type and parameter?):

```
public string CurrentWindowHandle
{
    get
    {
        return _driver.CurrentWindowHandle;
    }
}

public ReadOnlyCollection<string> WindowHandles
{
    get
    {
        return _driver.WindowHandles;
    }
}

public void Close()
{
    _driver.Close();
}

public void Quit()
{
    _driver.Quit();
}
```

I am just trying to add a string variable to the IWebDriver interface to keep track of which test is running.

EDIT: I found an alternative solution to my initial problem (which was proper logging of test results) that does not involve implementing any new functionality but rather placing try/catches in the correct places.

The solution to this question can be found in the marked answer as well as further below where @AlexanderWinter shows an example of an implementation including a way to retrieve data globally.

Thank you for all the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of extending the class, use external means to save the data. Something you can use is [`System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConditionalWeakTable<TKey, TValue>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287757(v=vs.110).aspx).

You could use it in the following way:

```
class TestState
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

//initialization of some private field
ConditionalWeakTable<IWebDriver, TestState> myTestsByDriver = new ConditionalWeakTable<IWebDriver, TestState>();

...

//usage:
myTestsByDriver.GetOrCreateValue().Name = "My_First_Test";
//etc.
```

Comment: Would this work with parallel test execution? i.e. multiple instances of WebDriver running simultaneously? Would it keep track of each pair created?

Comment: @Milo the dictionary itself is thread-safe, the `TestState` class is not. Until you don't try to update the state for the same driver from different threads, it should work.

Comment: So as long as it is initially set and not tampered w/ any further it should be OK?

Comment: @Milo yes, and even if you update it on the same thread, it's OK too.

Comment: Thank you I will try and report back.

Comment: Thank you @galenus for your help. I found an alternate to my problem (which was getting the logging to work properly) so I will not try to implement this any further. I will mark this the answer since it is the concept that matters and I've learned a lot!

Answer (score 2):

IWebDriver has no default behavior, it has no behavior at all because it's an interface.

Interfaces has no content, only method and events prototypes. What you want is to inherit a class that implements this interface. So being already implemented, you can edit this class. If you were inheriting a class, you could override only the method you want and even call the base methods using base.callToABaseMethod()

Here's an example

```
public interface IAnimal //this has no behavior at all, it's an interface
{
    void eat();
    string Name { get; }
}

public class Animal //this has a behavior you can modify
{
    private string m_name;

    public Animal(string name)
    {
        this.m_name = name;
    }

    public void eat()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(m_name + " is eating !");
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get { return m_name; }
    }
}

public class Cat : Animal //this is your class that changes the behavior 
{                         //of the Animal class
    public Cat(string name) : base("Cat " + name) //we always need to call 
    { }                                           //a base constructor

    public override void eat() //here we are overriding the eat method
    {
        base.eat(); //calling the Animal eat method
        Console.WriteLine("He is eating fish !"); //editing the methd a bit
    }

    //no need to change the behavior of the Name property so we do nothing here
}
```

So find the class that has the default behavior you were talking about and inherit this one instead.

Hope it helps.

**Edited to fit OP's needs:**

In the case of a sealed class, you can't use this solution to edit the class. That's the point of a sealed class but C# has extension methods.

galenus' solution is fine but asking to make an extra call from somewhere in the application might be confusing for the class user. What you can do is mix extension methods and an external dictionary to make a complete simulation of an extra property. However, since extension properties doesn't exist in C#, you will have to create methods like GetProperty and SetProperty.

Here's an example:

```
/// <summary>
/// An extension from the sealed StringBuilder class that saves 
/// a color with a StringBuilder !
/// </summary>
public static class StringBuilderExt
{
    private static readonly Dictionary<StringBuilder, Color> colors = new Dictionary<StringBuilder, Color>();

    public static void SetColor(this StringBuilder builder, Color color)
    {
        colors[builder] = color;
    }

    public static Color GetColor(this StringBuilder builder)
    {
        if(colors.ContainsKey(builder))
        {
            return colors[builder];
        }

        return Color.Black;
   }
}
```

Example usage:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

builder.SetColor(Color.Red);
Console.WriteLine(builder.GetColor().ToString());
```

But this is just a workaround, there's might be better ones. Try it and take what fits your needs the best.

Hope this will do

Comment: I understand and would have taken this approach but I can't seem to inherit from the WebDriver class only the IWebDriver interface. IntelliSense shows nothing for WebDriver or even RemoteWebDriver.

Comment: It might be a sealed class and if it is, your only choices are to copy-paste the code of this class (dirty) or not extending the class.

Comment: So I cannot do what I am trying in the Question? Just add a member and leave rest of functionality alone?

Comment: Well if the class is sealed, you can't that's the point of a sealed class. But I can't find the documentation of your classes so I don't know. galenus's solution looks like the best solution to me. You could even make an extension method that fetch the value from the dictionary.

Comment: Hey @AlexanderWinter I am trying to implement galenus's solution and I would indeed need a way to globally access this key/value pair as that is the point of this question (for logging purposes). Could you provide reference you an example?

Comment: Thanks @AlexanderWinter. I figured out an alternative to get the tests to log properly so I will not try to implement this any further but thank you and galenus for this important lesson, I hope I may utilize it in the future. And got me interested in Design Patterns in general!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Extension methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) to add functionality to functions instead of creating a wrapper around the entire class

Comment: I just want to add a member to the class, not necessarily extend any functionality. Just would like to know how to leave functions in their base states.

Comment: Why not just create a struct that has the member you want and the `IWebDriver` and just access it like `myStruct.myMember` and `myStruct.WebDriver.AnyMethod`? or keep track of the string in another variable instead of this way? Seems to be overcomplicating a simple task IMO, but I don't know what your end goal is.

Comment: I was thinking about this but it would take a big overhaul of my current project to implement since everything currently passes the WebDriver instance around. I can't really have it in another random string variable because it has to be tied to a specific instance of WebDriver due to parallel test execution.